# how to get unbound textbox values in devex AspxGridView

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I've an AspxGridView in my form. When I check it's select check box, I trigger ClientSideEvents event and get selected row values to a listbox:

```
<dx:ASPxListBox ID="listBox" ClientInstanceName="lb" runat="server"
    ValueType="System.String" Width="961px"></dx:ASPxListBox>
<ClientSideEvents SelectionChanged="grid_SelectionChanged" />

function grid_SelectionChanged(s, e) {
    s.GetSelectedFieldValues('A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I', GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);
}      

function GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback(selectedValues) {
        lb.ClearItems();
        if (selectedValues.length == 0) return;
        l = "";
        for (i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++) {
            s = "";
            for (j = 0; j < selectedValues[i].length; j++) {
                s = s + selectedValues[i][j] + " - ";
            }
            l = l + s + "\r\n";
            lb.AddItem(s);
        }
    }
```

In addition, when I add datatextcolumns for textboxes and update js function like as below, I get null values for textboxes.

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="textBox1" VisibleIndex="9">
    <Settings AllowHeaderFilter="False"></Settings>
    <DataItemTemplate>
       <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtBox1" Width="70" runat="server"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="textBox2" VisibleIndex="10">
    <Settings AllowHeaderFilter="False"></Settings>
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtBox2" Width="70" runat="server"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

function grid_SelectionChanged(s, e) {
    s.GetSelectedFieldValues('A;B;C;D;E;F;textBox1;textBox2;G;H;I',
                            GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback); 
}
```

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: just curious if you were able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your txtBox1 and txtBox2 fields are placed inside DataItemTemplate. When item is placed inside an DataItemTemplate you can't reference it directly by server side ID. What you need to do is to assign a unique ClientInstanceName to each ASPxTextBox you want to reference at each row.

See how DX support suggests to do that:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T273445

Basically, the idea is that you need to add the server side OnInit event handler to both textboxes:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtBox1" Width="70" runat="server" OnInit="OnTextBox1Init"/>

<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtBox2" Width="70" runat="server" OnInit="OnTextBox2Init"/>
```

and assign the "row's-visible-index-dependent" ClientInstanceName to each instance of the relevant textbox.

```
protected void OnTextBox1Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ASPxTextBox tb1 = sender as ASPxTextBox;
    GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer container = 
    tb1.NamingContainer as GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer;
    tb1.ClientInstanceName = String.Format("txtBox1_{0}", container.VisibleIndex);
}
```

Then you will be able to get the textbox value using this row-id-dependent ClientInstanceName by calling GetText() over it: txtBox1_1.GetText() for the first textbox at row #1, and so on.

Hope this explanation is enough for you to solve your task.